# How to make this website completely responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been building a website on my laptop since a month, the website looks all nice and dandy on my machine(15 inch screen. However when I run it on different machines(17 inch and 13 inch) ones, it all goes haphazard. I have used bootstrap, my website is responsive to some extent but not fully.

Since I don't fully know which all parts of the site and responsible for the "un-responsiveness", I will post the whole code here.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<title>Big Data for your city!</title>
</head>

<body>
 <header>  
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
    <div class = "navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="#" title="Explore around">
    <img style="max-width:150px; margin-top: -7px;"
         src="Images/logo.png">
</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">        
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1><center>Find amazing places near your city.</center></h1>
    <p>Places you could travel to and explore in a weekend.</p>
    <a class = "explore-anc" href="#Cities"><button id  "exlpore-button" class="btn sm explore">Explore</button></a>
    <p>OR</p>
    <div class = "seach-area">
     <form id="searchBox" action="/search" style="display:inline;" method="get">
        <center><input id="text-enter" name="q" size="80" type="text" placeholder="Enter a place "/>
        <input id="search-button" value="Search" type="submit"/></center>
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<div class="learn-more" id ="learn">
  <div class="container">
    <div class = "row">
      <div class = "col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="#Cities">Cities with service</a></h3>
        <p>Find all the cities here!</p>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-4">
        <h3><a href="#analytics">Analyze</a></h3>
        <p>Big data analyics</p>
      </div>

      <div class = "col-md-4">
        <h3><a href = "value.html">Vlue</a></h3>
        <p>Add value to all your stuff here!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = "Cities" class = "neighborhood-guides">
<div class = "container">
    <h2>Cities:</h2>
    <p>Start exploring places around your city</p>
    <div class = "row">
              <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class = "thumbnail" ng-click = "city  NY">
                    <image src = "Images/NY.jpg"/>
                </div>
                 <div class = "thumbnail" ng-click = "city  mum">
                    <image src = "Images/Mum.jpg"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "col-md-4">
              <div class = "thumbnail" ng-click = "city  SF">
                    <image src = "Images/SF.jpg"/>
                </div>
              <div class = "thumbnail" ng-click = "city  LA">
                    <image src = "Images/LA.jpg"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class = "col-md-4">
              <div class =  "thumbnail" ng-click = "city  del">
                    <image src = "Images/Del.jpg"/>
                </div>
              <div class = "thumbnail" ng-click = "city  MA">
                    <image src = "Images/MA.jpg"/>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "analytics" class = "analytics">
    <div class = "container">
     <div>
        <h2><center>Plan better with data</center></h2>
        <p>Data is constantly churned, filtered and updated. Forget numbers, use graphs and make your every trip a perfect one</p>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="Images/india-home.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
         <ul type = "">
            <li>Weather patterns, rainfall graphs on every city.</li>
            <li>Popularity pattern, interest rate graphs on each and every place</li>
            <li>The size of the circle in this map represents the number of places covered in that city</li>                
            <li>Go to your city and find analytics there. Also, each place get its own graphs</li>
         </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:
Navbar:

```
html, body{height: 100%;min-height:100%;}


header .navbar {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top:30px;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}
header .navbar-brand {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px 0;
  height: auto;
}
header .navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none !important;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:active {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
/**  Navbar Brand **/

header .navbar-brand {
    margin-left:0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}



/*Navbar toggle*/

header .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #279182;
}

header .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}

@media only screen
and (max-width: 768px) {
  header .navbar-collapse.in {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  }
}
/*Links Navbar*/
header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid white; 
}
header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:focus{
   color: white; 
}
header .navbar-default .navbar-nav a:hover {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid white; 
}
```

Main CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  background-image:url('Images/B.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.jumbotron .container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  top:105px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;  
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  opacity:1;
}

 .jumbotron p {
   font-size: 20px;
   color: #fff;
   text-align:center;
   font-weight: 700;
   opacity:1;
   padding-top:10px;
 }

.jumbotron a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width:15%;
 } 
.search-area{
    display:block;
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
 }

#search-button {  
   background:transparent;  
   color:white;
   font: 'trebuchet ms', trebuchet;
   padding:13px 25px;
   border-radius:0 9px 9px 0;
   -moz-border-radius:0 9px 9px 0;
   -webkit-border-radius:0 9px 9px 0;
   -o-border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
   border:2px solid white;
   font-weight:bold;
   margin-left:-4px;
 }

#search-button:hover{
 background-color: #5CDEBD;
 border: 2px solid #5CDEBD;
}

#text-enter {
background: white;
padding:15px;
 border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
  -o-border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
  border:0 none;
  width:30%;
 }

/*Learn*/

.learn-more {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #8715CE;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 17px;
 }

.learn-more h3 {
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: white;
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
.learn-more a:hover {
  background-color:white;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
  text-decoration:none;
}

/*neighborhood*/

.neighborhood-guides{
    background-color: #efefef;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
    min-height: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;

}

.neighborhood-guides .row .thumbnail{
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color:black;
}

.neighborhood-guides .row .thumbnail  img:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.neighborhood-guides .container{
    padding-top:25px;
}

.neighborhood-guides .container .row{
    padding-top:30px;
} 
.neighborhood-guides h2{
    padding-top:50px;
    font-weight:800;
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.neighborhood-guides p{
    margin-bottom:13px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.analytics
{
    background-color: #15CE68;    
    min-height: 130%;
    color:white;
}

.analytics ul li{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.analytics h2{
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-top:6%;
    font-size: 48px;
}
.analytics .container p{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.analytics img{
max-height: 600px;
}
```

If somebody could help me with this, I would be really grateful, this has been burdening me for a week now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but... Really? You are going to ask us to look at your _entire_ code and tell you how to make it responsive...? I am sorry, but that turns me off. The idea in Stack Overflow is that you try it yourself and ask us for help when you get stuck (and can't already find the answer on the vast Stack already)...

Comment: Sorry, I am  a novice programmer and new to stackoverflow, shouldn't I post the whole code?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware.

Comment: No problem, I don't downvote because of beginners mistakes :) Have a look at this meta article to see how this works: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Its not disallowed to post your entire code, but I doubt you will find people willing to read through and correct the whole lot to make it responsive - thats what web developers get paid for, so they don't really want to tackle the entire thing in their free time, if you see where I am going with this.

Comment: Oh, I understand, this won't be repeated again. The reason why I posted the whole code was because I didn't know which parts of the HTML/CSS were making it unresponsive.

Comment: That's okay, update the question when you know more and we can help you better. Good luck!

Comment: Good start will be to remove one jQuery script from your HTML (the second one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you might find helpful

- Remove the second jQuery link. You are already getting jQuery from the Google CDN
- Remove the *min-height* for your images, or use percentages instead of a fixed pixel value
- Always better to use percentages than fixed pixel length for the overall layout styles for your website
- Don't mix up with both percentage and pixel values for the same element, unless it is unavoidable